# The file has been deleted but still exists in the git commit?

Tags: git, github

Once I have add a file in a folder and tried to push it. But it is said that it exceed the size limit. Thus, I deleted it on my local disk. And later I tried to commit and push again(other changes) but got a same error:
`remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.` And then I tried `git reset`, `git commit --amend` but they all failed. And `git rm file` but it is not there anymore. This is so annoying. Could you help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: git rm should work on non-existent files if they are already in the cache. What's your git status? Also git reset --hard HEAD will force undo all your current changes (without --hard the changes will remain in the workarea).

Comment: @kabanus `On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean`

Comment: It looks like stuff is already in your commit history, so you need to undo the previous commit. Do a `git show --name-only HEAD` and see if the large file is in there.

Comment: @merlin2011 How? I tried this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-last-commits-in-git) but it doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure the last commit contained the large file and not a commit earlier in the history?

Comment: @merlin2011 solved. Thanks!

Comment: You could tell us the solution... ;)

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia Just reset to the last commit recorded in github. And then make a new commit again. Quite easy actually... :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a tool that delete all the large files from your history.

https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/